# Pass prop from child to parent React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In `WeatherForecast` component I need to pass the returned value of function `appColor` into a property. Then the property from `WeatherForecast` needs to be passed into `className` of `app` component. New to react. Not sure how to pass property from child to component.

```
class WeatherForecast extends Component {

  appColor(weatherData) {
    //Check for condition and return value
    return "example-color1"
  }

  render() {
    /************************************
    // Need to Pass returned value of Function into propery or variable?
    /************************************/ 
    let bgColor = appColor(weatherData);

    return (
      <div className="text-center col-xs-12">

         <h1 id="temp">{this.displayTemp(this.props.weather)}</h1>
         <h1>{this.displayCity(this.props.weather)}</h1> 

      </div>
    );
  }
}



export default class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={"app-container" + this.AppColorPropertyClass}>

        <div className="main-wrapper">

            <WeatherForecast bgColorPropertyClass={this.AppColorPropertyClass} />

        </div> 

      </div>  

    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass a function from the parent to the child, and the child can call that function with the color (pretty much operates like an event handler). When the color is received back in App, assign it to a state value using .setState() which will then get picked up in render()

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { appColorClass: 'some-default-color' };
  }

  setAppColor(colorClass) {
    this.setState({ appColorClass: colorClass });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={"app-container" + this.state.appColorClass}>

        <div className="main-wrapper">

          <WeatherForecast getBgColorPropertyClass={ color => this.setAppColor(color) } />

        </div>

      </div>

    );
  }
}


class WeatherForecast extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    if (this.props.getBgColorPropertyClass) {
      // TODO: Get "weatherData" from somewhere (maybe from this.props.weather ??)
      this.props.getBgColorPropertyClass(this.appColor(weatherData));
    }
  }

  appColor(weatherData) {
    //Check for condition and return value
    return "example-color1"
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="text-center col-xs-12">

         <h1 id="temp">{this.displayTemp(this.props.weather)}</h1>
         <h1>{this.displayCity(this.props.weather)}</h1> 

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```