# react pass props from child to parent undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40644066/pass-prop-from-child-to-parent-react) to pass props from child to parent component and it works fine.

When I submit the form, I get response state fine in my child component
But the problem is, I have to submit the form 2 times to get the props searchString in my parents component.

If I do a console.log on this line in my child component

```
this.props.getSearchString(this.getSearch());
```

I get undefined when I submit

Do you know where the problem come from?

**My parent component**

```
class Parents extends Component {
 constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { searchString :'' };
 }

 setSearchString(string) {
  this.setState({ searchString: string });
 }

 render() {
   return (
      <div>
         <p>Get Search String: {this.state.searchString}</p>
         <Child getSearchString={ mySearch => this.setSearchString(mySearch)} />
      </div>
   )
 }

}
```

**My Child Component**

```
class Child extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {value: '', response: ''};
     this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
     this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  getSearch() {
     return this.state.response;
  }

  handleChange(event) {
     this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     this.setState({response: this.state.value});
     this.props.getSearchString(this.getSearch());
  }

  render() {
     return (
       <div>
       <p>Response: {this.state.response}</p>
       <form className="searchForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input type="text"
                 className="searchInput"
                 value={this.state.value}
                 onChange={this.handleChange} />
          <button className="searchButton" type="submit">Ok</button>
       </form>
       </div>
  )}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't give parameters to child component.

```
<Child getSearchString={ () => this.setSearchString()} />
```

Comment: if I remove parameters I don't get searchString display at all